# In AngularJS static dropdown, change event is not firing back after changing the selected option dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have below static drop down in angularjs.

Step1. If *Dependent * option is selected then a button section is visible below. If other option is selected (i.e. 0 or 1) the button section is hidden. (done through ng-change event handler.)

Step2. if user clicks on the delete button then also delete section becomes hidden and the selected option is changed dynamically to value ="1" and **it reflects in the dropdown**. ( done through button click event handler)

Step3. if the user manually again selects the *dependent *option (i.e. "2") the delete section is not visible because the ng-change event is not firing. Change event fires in-case user selects any other value (i.e. "0") instead of value "2". and then selects "2".

I doubt step 3 is not working as expected because the dropdown selection is changed to "1" from "2" **through code** but the dropdown is still there internally. so when user changes the dropdown back to "2" it does not considers it a change in selection.

Please help me fix this issue.
**A running code example** in angular js would be appreciated.

```
<select id="CoverageType" name="CoverageType" ng-
model="CoverageType"
ng-change="vm.CoverageTypeChange">
<option></option>
<option ng-value="0">Employee</option>
<option ng-value="1">Employee + Spouse</option>
<option ng-value="2">Dependent</option>
</select>

<div ng-show="IsDependentSelected">
<a href="#"
class="btn btn-delete"
style="padding-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 6px"
ng-click="vm.deleteDependent(value, $event)">Delete</a>
</div>
```

On delete button click, its simply accessing the select element by id and assigning value.

Thank you.